A surface in the space of $n \times m$ matrices.
Question
We know that $M_{n \times m}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$. So let's suppose we take a smooth surface like sphere/torus in ${R}^{nm}$ and it's image via isomorphism in $M_{n \times m}$. Thus we will have a collection of matrices. Now let this set of matrices act on a fixed point $p$ of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Thus we will get a subset of $R^{m}$ such that each point is image of $p$ under some matrix from the set chosen above.
I wanted to ask can anything be said about this subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Is it a surface? Also, will will it depend on the choice of $p$.
Context
I studied differential geometry from the book Loring tu, few years back. The above question is not from any standard book (as far as I know), but something I was thinking.

Thanks a lot! That was helpful @MoisheKohan
